# UIManagedDocument saveToURL always returns false

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm trying to create a UIManagedDocument that doesn't yet exists. Here is my code:

```
url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"file://ProjectSSDB"];
document = [[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:url];

if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[url path]]) {
    [document openWithCompletionHandler: ^(BOOL success) {
        if (success) [ProjectSSViewController documentIsReady];
        if (!success) NSLog(@"Couldn't open document at %@", url);
    }];
} else {
    [document saveToURL:url forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
        NSLog(@"Returned %d", success);
        if (success) [ProjectSSViewController documentIsReady];
        if (!success) NSLog(@"Couldn't create document at %@", url);
    }];
}
```

My problem is that the file doesn't exist yet, and the saveToURL operation always seems to be returning false. Is there anyway I can debug this further as to why this is happening?

**EDIT:**

Ok, so I can't write to that URL. I've now tried doing this:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:documentsDirectory];

NSLog(@"The URL is %@", [url absoluteString]);
```

When it runs, the log seems to return that the URL is null. Is there something else that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I have updated my answer, use the code that I've posted

Answer (score 1):

You can't write at this path "file://ProjectSSDB", you don't have the permission, you need to get the root of your application in this way:

```
NSString* rootPath = NSHomeDirectory();
```

and save the the data in one of the sub folder as specified by [Apple file system guide line](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html)

```
NSString* fullPath = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"subFoldeder/file.extension"];
```

Comment: I've tried doing something similar, I've updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

I've been successfully using following code snippet for generating `UIManagedDocument`'s **URL** for quite a while:

```
NSURL *url = [NSFileManager.defaultManager URLsForDirectory:NSLibraryDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask].firstObject;
url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"ARBITRARY_NAME"];

self.document = [UIManagedDocument.alloc initWithFileURL:url];
```

*P.s.: it's iOS 5+ solution.*

Let me know if that works for you ;)